# Редирект в htacces со страницы с массивами в GET-параметрах

Tags: .htaccess, get, редирект

Как выглядит правило для редиректа в htaccess:
с /katalog/?p=3&f[zone]=440&f[style][0]=452
на /katalog/klassika/stolovaya/

Сложность вызывает наличие массива в get в виде квадратных скобок. С обычными параметрами проблем не возникает.

Comment: Экранирование квадратных скобок сделайте через `\\` в правилах.

Comment: помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Правильный редирект с экранированными скобками выглядит так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=3 [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} f\[zone\]=440 [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} f\[style\]\[0\]=452 [NC]
RewriteRule ^katalog/$ /katalog/? [R=301,L]
```